# Trying to Create a listView image with text in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, listview, android-inflate

```
package com.example.test;
import android.content.Context;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
public class ProgramAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Context context;
    int[] images;
    String[] programName;
    String[] programDescription;
    public ProgramAdapter( Context context, String [] programName,  int[] images, String[] programDescription) {
        super(context, R.layout.single_item, R.id.textView1, programName);
        this.context = context;
        this.images = images;
        this.programName = programName;
        this.programDescription = programDescription; }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position,  View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {
        View singleItem = convertView;
        ProgramViewHolder holder = null;
        if(singleItem == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            singleItem = LayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ProgramViewHolder(singleItem);
        singleItem.setTag(holder); }
        else{
            holder = (ProgramViewHolder) singleItem.getTag(); }
        holder.itemImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
        holder.programTitle.setText(programName[position]);
        holder.programDescription.setText(programDescription[position]);
        singleItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You clicked:" + programName[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            }
        });
        return singleItem;
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a Listview image with text in Android Studio. There is only one error shown up in the following line:

```
singleItem = LayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);
```

I have 3 classes: MainActivity, ProgramAdapter and ProgramViewHolder

> Non-static method 'inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean)' cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Please note the conventions for formatting [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Already done for you in this case!

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `layoutInflater` object

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

`LayoutInflater` is a class.

```
singleItem = LayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);
```

Change it to

```
singleItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);
```